# Gulp-uglify combine multiple javascript files into a single javascript file

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, gulp, grunt-contrib-uglify, gulp-uglify

I'm searching for ***Gulp task*** that can take multiple javascript files into a single javascript file and compress to one file, like **grunt-contrib-uglify**.

This what I tried to do so for to simulate grunt-contrib-uglify:

```
gulp.task('compressJS', function ()
{
    return gulp.src(SomeJSArrayWithALotOfFiles)
        .pipe(concat('application.js'))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../application'))
}
```

**My problem** with this solution:
I need manually delete the file (application.js.min) before I run the task, otherwise every task execution the new files concatenate to old compressed file (because this line: `.pipe(concat('application.js')`)).

Comment: Why the unvote? this is a **very good** question and I did a big search before I asked it

Answer (score 3):

In your `SomeJSArrayWithALotOfFiles`, exclude all files that end with `.min.js`.

As array, including all `.js`, but excluding `.min.js` files:

```
[ '**/*.js', '!**/*.min.js' ]
```

Or as single string, including all `.js` files not ending in `.min.js`:

```
'**/*!(.min).js'
```

Comment: My problem is not the source, the problem is the destination file, please read the question again!

Comment: If you don't include the old `.min.js` file in your src, it won't be concatinated or included in the other operations. So I fail to see how this doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: @cheziHoyzer your problem is indeed the source glob.